# Update xAxis individual label position for printing Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to update specific xAxis label when a user wants to print the chart?

This is the initial chart (inverted column with custom styles). I created xAxis labels with formatter function

```
 xAxis: {
        arrowOnEnd: true,
        labels: {
          x: 40,
          formatter: function() {
            if (this.isLast) { return 'Less Likely' }
            if (this.isFirst) { return 'More Likely' }
          }
        },
```

and was able to position them so it looks like inverted xAxis has values from *Less likely* to *More likely* as follows

```
 events: {
          load: function() {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656849/xaxis-point-specific-label-positions
            const chart = this;
            Highcharts.objectEach(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function(tick: any) {
              if (!tick.isNewLabel && tick.isFirst) { tick.label.attr({ y: 25 })}
              if (!tick.isNewLabel && tick.isLast)  { tick.label.attr({ y: 590 })}
            });
          },
```

[image: Inverted column chart]

The **problem** I have is when I want to print the chart:
xAxis labels gets back to its original location. 
[image: print chart]

I tried to replicate `events: { load: ... }` logic in `beforePrint` or wrapping 'print' event to highcharts object, but that doesn't seem to take any effect

```
 beforePrint: function() {
   const chart = this;
   Highcharts.objectEach(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function(tick: any) {
     if (tick.isFirst) { tick.label.attr({ y: 125 })}
     if (tick.isLast) { tick.label.attr({ y: 590 })}
   });
}
```

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'print', function (proceed) {
      const chart = this;
      Highcharts.objectEach(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function(tick: any) {
        if (tick.isFirst) { tick.label.attr({ y: 25 })}
        if (tick.isLast)  { tick.label.attr({ y: 590 })}
      });
      proceed.call(this)
  });
```

I tried `tickPositionier` but couldn't actually work out how to make that work.

Worth to mention. that `afterPrint` event with the same logic resets the chart, so I don't understand why one event is working (afterPrint) but the other doesn't (print)

```
 afterPrint: function() {
            const chart = this;
            Highcharts.objectEach(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function(tick: any) {
              if (tick.isFirst) { tick.label.attr({ y: 25 })}
              if (tick.isLast)  { tick.label.attr({ y: 590 })}
            });
          },
```

Am I missing something here? Why I can't update tick position for printing?

Sidenote - jsfiddle gives me `502 Bad Gateway` so I'm unable to demo it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the load event to render should fix the issue when the chart will be initialized again before the print.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4qbp1w0z/

```
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656849/xaxis-point-specific-label-positions
        const chart = this;
        Highcharts.objectEach(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function(tick) {
          if (!tick.isNewLabel && tick.isFirst) {
            tick.label.attr({
              y: 20
            })
          }
          if (!tick.isNewLabel && tick.isLast) {
            tick.label.attr({
              y: 350
            })
          }
        });
      },
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render